Solutions to $\ddot{\gamma} \times\gamma =0$ where $\|\gamma(t)\|=1$
I was brushing up on geodesics and I need to find the solutions to $\ddot{\gamma}(t) \times \gamma(t) =0$ where $\|\gamma(t)\|=1$ and $\gamma: I\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ a $C^1$ curve. My attempt is to say that the components of the vector $\gamma(t)$ denoted respectively $\gamma_i$ in cartesian coordinates (so by imbedding $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$) satisfy for all $t\in I$:
$$\frac{\ddot\gamma_1(t)}{\gamma_1(t)}=\frac{\ddot\gamma_2(t)}{\gamma_2(t)}=\frac{\ddot\gamma_3(t)}{\gamma_3(t)}$$
(this is easy to find when you expand the cross product in cartesian product and identify to the zero vector). My idea was like when solving the heat equation, find the existence of a seperation constant s.t $\frac{\ddot\gamma_i(t)}{\gamma_i(t)}=C<0$ which would yield for each component a sinusoidal solution, leading to the wanted great circle, but this looks false. I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this system of differential equations.

LaTeX tip: it's better to use \| instead of ||

I'm going to switch from $\gamma$ to $u$ to make typing easier.
From $u'' \times u = 0$, you know that $u''$ is a multiple of $u$ (although the multiplier may depend on $t$), so we have
$$
u''(t) = c(t)u(t)
$$
(I've put the $c$ on the right because we know that $u$ is nonzero.)
Let's just think a moment...we want to show that the curve $u$ is a plane curve, for the intersection of a plane (through the origin) and the sphere is a great circle, so this will show that the image of $u$ lies in a great circle. If we think of how $u$ starts out, it starts at $u(0)$ headed in direction $u'(0)$, i.e., in the plane defined by the basis $u(0)$ and $u'(0)$, i.e., orthogonal to $u(0) \times u'(0)$. If we could show that this was always true, we'd be done. So let's look at
$$
B(t) = u(t) \times u'(t)
$$
(that's more or less the binormal in the Frenet frame of $u$, except it's not a unit vector in general, but $B$ still seems like a good name). Let's look at the derivative of $B$:
\begin{align}
B'(t)
&= u'(t) \times u'(t) + u(t) \times u''(t) & \text{using deriv. of cross-prod. rule} \\
&= u'(t) \times u'(t) + u(t) \times c u(t) & \text{using the first displayed equation} \\
&= u'(t) \times u'(t) & \text{because $X \times X$ is always zero} \\
&= 0 & \text{again because $X \times X$ is always zero} \\
\end{align}
Whoa! So $B(t)$ is a constant vector. And it's orthogonal to $u(t)$ for every $t$. That means that the image of the path $u$ lies in the plane defined by
$$
B(0) \cdot X = 0.
$$
Hence it lies on a great circle.
Note that it does not need to actually describe a great circle. $u$ could be a constant, for instance. If it's not a constant, then maybe it has to describe a great circle, but I leave that to you. It might help to switch to a coordinate system in which $B$ is proportional to $(0,0,1)$, and $u(0) = (1, 0, 0)$, for this is then a problem in the $xy$-plane, and should be amenable to simpler methods.
